# Is it possible to create a appxupload without Visual Studio?

Tags: java, windows, visual-studio

I have a desktop app built in Java, so I can create an EXE with innoSetup easily.

Now I want to upload to Windows Store, and they asked me for a appxupload.

I see everywhere you need Visual Studio to create this, but I don't have it ... is there any way to create the appxupload without Visual Studio ?

Comment: and is it possible to create an appxupload with VS from an EXE or JAR ? I mean, no necessary to create from visual studio language (c or whatever it is :P )

Comment: no you need rebuild app using any languages you know like vb, c#, Html, JS, c++ . you cannot convert directly

Comment: Rebuild app? I hope you don't mean recode in other language ... please, tell me how to "load" the jar/exe into visual studio in order to create the appxupload

Comment: Yes, I have source code in Java ... but rebuilt is not recode, right?

Comment: So, summarizing ... is it IMPOSSIBLE to upload something to Windows Store if it's not coded in vb, c#, Html, JS or c++ ?

Comment: yes if u want use vs you have to know any of this languages